# Android, List of items not showing correctly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Got a list (recyclerview) that should show an image for certain types of Class X, everything is working perfectly, the thing is that after I start another activity and finish to go back to it, all of the images are removed, except for the ones that don't have a type 1 after them, so it seems there is a reason that causes if type 1 doesn't make its image only gone, but all the previous

```
private class XHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mImageView;
    private X mX;

    private XHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    }

    public void bindX(X x){
        mX = x;

        if(mX.getType() == 1) {
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        xClickEvent(mX);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add else condition too, like:

```
if (mX.getType() == 1) {
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  } else {
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

RecyclerView does not inflate your View every time, it rather uses the View going out of the screen in the onBindViewHolder() for the next item to appear. So you need to handle if and else condition both each time.